# Pivoting a pandas dataframe with json data

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have a pandas dataframe with some rows containing json data

| Date | message |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | { 'var1': 'foo'} |
| 2020-01-01 | different content |
| 2020-01-01 | { 'var2': 'foo'} |
| 2020-01-02 | non json content |
| 2020-01-02 | { 'var2': 'bar'} |

I would like to pivot the table so that I have a time series of the different variables, like

| Date | var1 | var2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | foo | foo |
| 2020-01-02 | nan/empty | bar |

Answer (score 0):

Convert values to `Series` with convert jsons to dicts, last get first non missing value per datetimes by [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
import ast


def f(x):
    try:
        return pd.Series(ast.literal_eval(x))
    except SyntaxError:
        return pd.Series()

df = df.set_index('Date')['message'].apply(f).groupby(level=0).first()
print (df)
            var1 var2
Date                 
2020-01-01   foo  foo
2020-01-02  None  bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your data exactly looks like, but you could do the following

- Use `pd.json_normalize()` to parse some of the nested json content
- Then use `groupby()` to get for example the first result

Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd

#Input data
data = {
        "Date": ["2020-01-01","2020-01-01","2020-01-01","2020-01-02","2020-01-02"],
        "message": [{'var1': 'foo'}, {'stupidkey':'stupidval'}, {'var2':'foo'}, "bla", {'var2':'bar'}]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Generate result
varsToKeep = ["var1", "var2"]
df_vars = pd.json_normalize(df["message"])[varsToKeep]
df = df.join(df_vars)
df_result = df.groupby("Date").first()[varsToKeep]
```

Comment: I will try this solution. My input data is a .csv with the table above which I read in a first step into a pandas dataframe